# C# ASP.NET MVC model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

in ASP.NET MVC i was trying to bind a model field with displayText with code below:

```
<%    if (Model.WillAttend == true)
           Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.Name);   %>
```

but when i tried:

```
<%    if (Model.WillAttend == true)     %>  
         <% = Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.Name)     %>
```

it is working, why?
both seems same code, the only different is in below one is just each line is separated with the server side tag.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the `=` sign after the open tag `<%`. This ensures that the value is written to the output. The first example is simply declaring a value and not doing anything with it.

Check out [this blog entry for more info on the ASPX view engine tag syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx).

This is simplified a lot with Razor syntax, where you are able to just [prefix a line in a codeblock with @ in order to write it to output](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/razor-code-nuggets-vs-code-blocks/). I don't know if there is a similar functionality in the ASPX view engine though.

Comment: so u mean we cant write all the c# code within a single server side tag (`<% %>`) ?

Comment: Not a single one no, not that I can find at least (I've only really worked with the Razor syntax). Code that you want to output needs some way of writing it to the output, hence the `<%=` syntax.

Comment: You can declare a string though, and just output that in the end, but I'm not sure that would be easily readable.

Comment: there is no "classic" MVC, there are different View Engines. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467850/ASP-NET-MVC-view-engines

Comment: @RobertP. ASPX, that's the word i was looking for. Thanks. :)